# how to use multiple theme globally?

Tags: html, angular

I am creating a setting page for my angular app.

It has an option of dark and light theme with a radio button.

setting.component.html

```
<div class="col">
 <input type="radio" value="Dark" (click)="blackTheme()" [(ngModel)]="themeselector">
 <label for="radio" class="pl-3 clr">Dark </label>
</div>

<div class="col">
 <input type="radio" (click)="whiteTheme()" [(ngModel)]="themeselector">
 <label for="radio" class="pl-3 clr">Light </label>
</div>
```

setting.component.ts

```
 themeselectors(){
    if(this.radiochecked){
      this.themeselector = true;
    }
    else{
      this.themeselector = false;
    }
  }


  blackTheme() {
    document.getElementById("main-theme").style.backgroundImage = "url('../assets/2/2.png')";
    localStorage.setItem('radiochecked', 'true');
    var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("clr");
    for (var i=0; i < cls.length; i++){
      const c = cls[i] as HTMLElement;
        c.style.color = 'white'
    }
  }

  whiteTheme() {
    document.getElementById("main-theme").style.backgroundImage = "url('../assets/3/3.png')";
    localStorage.setItem('radiochecked', 'true');
    var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("clr");
    for (var i=0; i < cls.length; i++){
      const c = cls[i] as HTMLElement;
        c.style.color = 'black'
        c.style.borderColor = 'black'
    }
  }
```

It works on the setting component but it doesn't work when navigating to other components. How do i make it work globally?

Comment: you should move the logic to app.component.html

Comment: use mixins and define your styles in your main `styles.css` or `styles.scss` and check the selected theme from lacal storage like: `checkTheTheme(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("themeSelected")==="foo"){
      this.foo = "foo";
    }else{
      this.foo = "bar";

    }
  }`

Comment: @iLuvLogix  Can you make it clear with an answer? Especially how i am gonna set a scss file in ts file?

Comment: You can set the css/scss file in your .ts via `@Component({
  selector: 'app-foobar',
  templateUrl: './foobar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foobar.component.scss']
})`

Comment: When I find the time I'll write you an answer after midday-break ;)

Comment: i will appreciate the answer @iLuvLogix